# Issue while running program in python

Tags: python

I have below files

my_test.py

```
import my_debugger
debugger =my_debugger.debugger()
debugger.load("C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe")
```

my_debugger.py

```
from ctypes import *
from my_debugger_defines import *

kernel32 = windll.kernel32

class debugger():
def __init__(self):
    pass


def load(self, path_to_exe):
 creation_flags = DEBUG_PROCESS
 startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
 process_information = PROCESS_INFORMATION
 startupinfo.dwflags =0x1
 startupinfo.wShowWindow = 0x0
 startupinfo.cb = sizeof(startupinfo)

 if kernel32.CreateProcessA(path_to_exe, None, None, None, None, byref(startupinfo),byref(process_information)):
     print( "[*] we have succedfully lanunched the prcoess")
     print ("[*] PID:  %d" % process_information.dwProcessId)
 else:
     print("[*} error: 0x%08x." % kernel32.GetLastError())
```

my_debugger_defines.py

```
from ctypes import *

# mirosoft types to ctypes

WORD = c_ushort
DWORD =c_ulong
LPBYTE = POINTER(c_ubyte)
LPTSTR = POINTER(c_char)
HANDLE = c_void_p

#constants


DEBUG_PROCESS = 0X00000001
CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0X00000010

#structures for createpressa() fuction
class STARTUPINFO(Structure):
_fields_ = [
    ("cb",    DWORD),
    ("lpReserved",   LPTSTR),
    ("lpDesktop",   LPTSTR),
    ("lpTitle",     LPTSTR),
    ("dwX",        DWORD),
    ("dwY",        DWORD),
        ("dwXSize",    DWORD),
    ("dwYsize",    DWORD),
    ("dsXCountChars",   DWORD),
    ("dwYCountChars",   DWORD),
    ("dwFillAttribute", DWORD),
    ("dwFlags", DWORD),
    ("wShowWindow", WORD),
    ("cbReserved2", WORD),
    ("lpReserved2", LPBYTE),
    ("hStdInput", HANDLE),
    ("hStdOutput", HANDLE),
    ("hStdError", HANDLE),
]

class PROCESS_INFORMATION(Structure):
 _fields_ = [
  ("hProcess", HANDLE),
  ("HtHREAD",  HANDLE),
  ("dwProcessId", DWORD),
  ("dwThreadId", DWORD),
]
```

when I run my_test.py I got below error

```
C:\download\New folder (6) (1)\Programowanie>python my_test.py
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_test.py", line 3, in 
    debugger.load("C:\windows\system32\calc.exe")
  File "C:\download\New folder (6) (1)\Programowanie\my_debugger.py", line 19, in load
    if kernel32.CreateProcessA(path_to_exe, None, None, None, None, byref(startupinfo),byref(process_information)):
TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not '_ctypes.PyCStructType'

C:\download\New folder (6) (1)\Programowanie>

do you know how to fix error?

Comment: `process_information` is a ctypes *type*, not an instance/object.

Comment: ok, but how to correct this

Comment: Calling a type or class (using parentheses on it) creates an object of this type.

Comment: ok, thanks for this. But which piece of code should use for this/

Comment: Currently you set `process_information = PROCESS_INFORMATION`. Change it the described way.

Comment: is it sth like this process_information = ctypes (PROCESS_INFORMATION)

Comment: No, a ctypes type is just like a Python type/class. Objects of it are created in the same way.

Comment: Sorry but I do not really inderstand, could you explain in more details. Thanks

Comment: Could anyone assist with it?